# load data using sql loader based on string values

Tags: unix, oracle11g, sql-loader

I have a dataset which is like

> 1,2,3,4,5,{1,2,3,4},{1,2,3,4}

I want to load the data as

```
 columnA ColumnB ColumnC ColumnD ColumnE ColumnF   COlumnG
 1       2       3       4       5       {1,2,3,4} {1,2,3,4}
```

I have used columnF and ColumnG as clob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enclose your dataset as

```
"1","2","3","4","5","{1,2,3,4}","{1,2,3,4}"
```

The control file must read

```
LOAD DATA
  INFILE *
Truncate
INTO TABLE IMPORT_TEST
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' optionally enclosed by '"'
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(columnA,columnB,columnC,columnD,columnE,columnF,columnG)
begindata
"columnA","columnB","columnC","columnD","columnE","columnF","columnG"
"1","2","3","4","5","{1,2,3,4}","{1,2,3,4}"
```